# Проверка полей на заполненность

Tags: javascript, frontend

У меня есть простая форма регистрации. Хочу в случае если пользователь не заполнил одно из полей, выводить сообщение. Новичок в js, поэтому немного запутался в функции проверки.

HTML:

```
  <form class = 'login-form'>
  <div class = "flex-row">
  <input name = "username" class='lf--input' placeholder='Имя пользователя' type='text'>
  </div>
  <div class = "flex-row">
  <input name = "password" class='lf--input' placeholder='Пароль' type='password'>
  </div>
  <button type = "button" class='lf--submit' onclick="alerted();"> Войти </button>
  <button type = "button" class='lf--forgot' onclick="openForm()"> Регистрация</button>
  </form>
```

JS:

```
function alerted() {

  {
    valid = true;

    if (document.getElementById("username") == "") {
      alert ("Пожалуйста заполните поле.");
      valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Смотри, выбирай... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: [Валидация форм на стороне клиента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: Спасибо! Решил!